# get data from child components to parents components in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get value from child components to parent components.

Here is my code.

//this is child component

```
import { React } from "react";

const Tab = () => {
  const changeTab = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex gap-10">
        <button
          onClick={() => changeTab(1)}
          className="bg-gray-700 p-2 text-white"
        >
          btn1
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```

//this is parent component

```
import React from "react";
import Nav1 from "./Components/Navbar/Nav1";
import Tab from "./Tab";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Tab />
      <div>
        <Nav1 />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want to log the value of the index in a parent component that was coming from a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define `changeTab` in parent component and pass it through props to `Tab`.

parent:

```
import React from "react";
import Nav1 from "./Components/Navbar/Nav1";
import Tab from "./Tab";

const App = () => {
    const changeTab = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
    };

  return (
    <>
      <Tab changeTab={changeTab}/>
      <div>
        <Nav1 />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and child component:

```
import { React } from "react";

const Tab = ({changeTab}) => {
  const onChangeTab = (index) => {
    changeTab(index);
    // other stuff
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex gap-10">
        <button
          onClick={() => onChangeTab(1)}
          className="bg-gray-700 p-2 text-white"
        >
          btn1
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```

Comment: Using callbacks as suggested above is the best way to pass data from child to parent. If you need the data to be centralized and be used across the whole app, consider using Context or Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context API:

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Or you can transfer changeTab function to parent component and pas it as prop

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is common(with most people). And the solution is to lift the state up([React docs](https://(https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html))).
Which basically means, you'll have to maintain the state in the parent component and pass the value and method to the child component.

```
// App.jsx
import React from "react";
import Nav1 from "./Components/Navbar/Nav1";
import Tab from "./Tab";

const App = () => {

  const changeTab = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tab handleTabChange={changeTab}/>
      <div>
        <Nav1 />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import { React } from "react";

const Tab = (props) => {
  const changeTab = (index) => {
    props.handleTabChange(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex gap-10">
        <button
          onClick={() => changeTab(1)}
          className="bg-gray-700 p-2 text-white"
        >
          btn1
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```